# What is the purpose of the game over screen's score listing?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What is the purpose of the game over screen's score listing? How can I get points?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit:** As of Beta 1.9, the score displayed on the Game Over screen is the amount of experience that the player has collected throughout that life.

---

**Old Answer:**
<s>You cannot currently earn points in Minecraft. Notch intended on adding a points system to Minecraft that would display upon dying, but it was never implemented. However, the placeholder text still shows on the Game Over screen. *Perhaps something in the upcoming "Adventure Update" will make use of points.*</s>

Comment: I know that xp point will be available for skills points and buy some upgrade. Dunno if it will affect the score board :S

Comment: In the videos previewing 1.8 notch explicitly said "We left the score the same" either meaning they hadn't got around to it yet, or they're purposely leaving it the same as a kind of in joke.

Answer (score -1):

Since Minecraft: Java Edition Indev 20100130, the scoreboard was removed, and score was added on Minecraft: Java Edition Classic 0.24 SURVIVAL_TEST, which was released on August 31, 2009. In this, scoreboard was shown and it was added on Minecraft: Java Edition Classic 0.25 SURVIVAL_TEST, which was released on September 3, 2009. When you die, it says "Game over!" until the full released of Minecraft: Java Edition 1.0.0, but, when you are on between Indev (the release of January 30, 2010) and Infdev (the release of June 30, 2010), it says "Score: 0", however, it was never added during Infdev, Alpha, and Beta periods. You cannot earn points on Minecraft: Java Edition Indev (the release of January 30, 2010)/Infdev (the release of February 27, 2010), which you die, it says "Score: 0", although, killing mobs and animals, it does not affect experience. On Minecraft: Java Edition Beta 1.9 Prerelease 2, the score was re-added, due to the Notch shows, they died on Hardcore mode, one day before release, this version.

However, you can modify score, by using NBTExplorer, which allows you to set any score, for example, if the score is 300,530,650, the maximum can go up to 2,147,483,467, due to the Java's 32-bit limit. For example, if the player tries to modify score, i.e. 1, 10, 545, 3,333 (without commas in this game), 78,443, 748,312, 1,543,123, 777,777, 7,777,777, 16,777,216, 536,870,912, or 2,147,483,647. If the player dies, with score with 56,483, or 1,542,463,687, this reads as "Game over!" (outdated title, replaced with "You died! on Minecraft: Java Edition 1.0.0"), and score says, and reads, as "Score: 56483", or "Score: 1542463687", however, if you are on Beta 1.6.4, the score reads "&e0", because of outdated experience since Beta 1.8 Pre-release.

The maximum score, on Infdev, can go up to 2,147,483,647, and if the player dies, the score says "Score: 2174846347", because due to the 32-bit limit.

Comment: You seem to have a particular love for versions. And other numbered things. But, although informative, you failed to answer the question "what is the purpose of the score listing?".